# How to change a block cipher algorithms ciphertext and plaintext length

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography

I am designing an encryption program. I use the Sm4 block cipher algorithm. Now, my program requires ciphertext and plaintext to be 64bit long and the key to be 128bit long, but the sm4's ciphertext and plaintext is 128bit long. I try more different way, but the result of the decrypt is incorrect. How can I change it to 64Bit?

This is the source code:

sm4.h:

```
/**
 * \file sm4.h
 */
#ifndef XYSSL_SM4_H
#define XYSSL_SM4_H

#define SM4_ENCRYPT     1
#define SM4_DECRYPT     0

/**
 * \brief          SM4 context structure
 */
typedef struct
{
    int mode;                   /*!<  encrypt/decrypt   */
    unsigned long sk[32];       /*!<  SM4 subkeys       */
}
sm4_context;


#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/**
 * \brief          SM4 key schedule (128-bit, encryption)
 *
 * \param ctx      SM4 context to be initialized
 * \param key      16-byte secret key
 */
void sm4_setkey_enc( sm4_context *ctx, unsigned char key[16] );

/**
 * \brief          SM4 key schedule (128-bit, decryption)
 *
 * \param ctx      SM4 context to be initialized
 * \param key      16-byte secret key
 */
void sm4_setkey_dec( sm4_context *ctx, unsigned char key[16] );

/**
 * \brief          SM4-ECB block encryption/decryption
 * \param ctx      SM4 context
 * \param mode     SM4_ENCRYPT or SM4_DECRYPT
 * \param length   length of the input data
 * \param input    input block
 * \param output   output block
 */
void sm4_crypt_ecb( sm4_context *ctx,
                     int mode,
                     int length,
                     unsigned char *input,
                     unsigned char *output);

/**
 * \brief          SM4-CBC buffer encryption/decryption
 * \param ctx      SM4 context
 * \param mode     SM4_ENCRYPT or SM4_DECRYPT
 * \param length   length of the input data
 * \param iv       initialization vector (updated after use)
 * \param input    buffer holding the input data
 * \param output   buffer holding the output data
 */
void sm4_crypt_cbc( sm4_context *ctx,
                     int mode,
                     int length,
                     unsigned char iv[16],
                     unsigned char *input,
                     unsigned char *output );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* sm4.h */
```

sm4.c

```
/*
 * SM4 Encryption alogrithm (SMS4 algorithm)
 * GM/T 0002-2012 Chinese National Standard ref:http://www.oscca.gov.cn/ 
 * thanks to Xyssl
 * thnaks and refers to http://hi.baidu.com/numax/blog/item/80addfefddfb93e4cf1b3e61.html
 * author:goldboar
 * email:goldboar@163.com
 * 2012-4-20
 */

// Test vector 1
// plain: 01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef fe dc ba 98 76 54 32 10
// key:   01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef fe dc ba 98 76 54 32 10
//     round key and temp computing result:
//     rk[ 0] = f12186f9 X[ 0] = 27fad345
//         rk[ 1] = 41662b61 X[ 1] = a18b4cb2
//         rk[ 2] = 5a6ab19a X[ 2] = 11c1e22a
//         rk[ 3] = 7ba92077 X[ 3] = cc13e2ee
//         rk[ 4] = 367360f4 X[ 4] = f87c5bd5
//         rk[ 5] = 776a0c61 X[ 5] = 33220757
//         rk[ 6] = b6bb89b3 X[ 6] = 77f4c297
//         rk[ 7] = 24763151 X[ 7] = 7a96f2eb
//         rk[ 8] = a520307c X[ 8] = 27dac07f
//         rk[ 9] = b7584dbd X[ 9] = 42dd0f19
//         rk[10] = c30753ed X[10] = b8a5da02
//         rk[11] = 7ee55b57 X[11] = 907127fa
//         rk[12] = 6988608c X[12] = 8b952b83
//         rk[13] = 30d895b7 X[13] = d42b7c59
//         rk[14] = 44ba14af X[14] = 2ffc5831
//         rk[15] = 104495a1 X[15] = f69e6888
//         rk[16] = d120b428 X[16] = af2432c4
//         rk[17] = 73b55fa3 X[17] = ed1ec85e
//         rk[18] = cc874966 X[18] = 55a3ba22
//         rk[19] = 92244439 X[19] = 124b18aa
//         rk[20] = e89e641f X[20] = 6ae7725f
//         rk[21] = 98ca015a X[21] = f4cba1f9
//         rk[22] = c7159060 X[22] = 1dcdfa10
//         rk[23] = 99e1fd2e X[23] = 2ff60603
//         rk[24] = b79bd80c X[24] = eff24fdc
//         rk[25] = 1d2115b0 X[25] = 6fe46b75
//         rk[26] = 0e228aeb X[26] = 893450ad
//         rk[27] = f1780c81 X[27] = 7b938f4c
//         rk[28] = 428d3654 X[28] = 536e4246
//         rk[29] = 62293496 X[29] = 86b3e94f
//         rk[30] = 01cf72e5 X[30] = d206965e
//         rk[31] = 9124a012 X[31] = 681edf34
// cypher: 68 1e df 34 d2 06 96 5e 86 b3 e9 4f 53 6e 42 46
//      
// test vector 2
// the same key and plain 1000000 times coumpting 
// plain:  01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef fe dc ba 98 76 54 32 10
// key:    01 23 45 67 89 ab cd ef fe dc ba 98 76 54 32 10
// cypher: 59 52 98 c7 c6 fd 27 1f 04 02 f8 04 c3 3d 3f 66

#include "sm4.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * 32-bit integer manipulation macros (big endian)
 */
#ifndef GET_ULONG_BE
#define GET_ULONG_BE(n,b,i)                             \
{                                                       \
    (n) = ( (unsigned long) (b)[(i)    ] << 24 )        \
        | ( (unsigned long) (b)[(i) + 1] << 16 )        \
        | ( (unsigned long) (b)[(i) + 2] <<  8 )        \
        | ( (unsigned long) (b)[(i) + 3]       );       \
}
#endif

#ifndef PUT_ULONG_BE
#define PUT_ULONG_BE(n,b,i)                             \
{                                                       \
    (b)[(i)    ] = (unsigned char) ( (n) >> 24 );       \
    (b)[(i) + 1] = (unsigned char) ( (n) >> 16 );       \
    (b)[(i) + 2] = (unsigned char) ( (n) >>  8 );       \
    (b)[(i) + 3] = (unsigned char) ( (n)       );       \
}
#endif

/*
 *rotate shift left marco definition
 *
 */
#define  SHL(x,n) (((x) & 0xFFFFFFFF) << n)
#define ROTL(x,n) (SHL((x),n) | ((x) >> (32 - n)))

#define SWAP(a,b) { unsigned long t = a; a = b; b = t; t = 0; }

/*
 * Expanded SM4 S-boxes
 /* Sbox table: 8bits input convert to 8 bits output*/

static const unsigned char SboxTable[16][16] = 
{
{0xd6,0x90,0xe9,0xfe,0xcc,0xe1,0x3d,0xb7,0x16,0xb6,0x14,0xc2,0x28,0xfb,0x2c,0x05},
{0x2b,0x67,0x9a,0x76,0x2a,0xbe,0x04,0xc3,0xaa,0x44,0x13,0x26,0x49,0x86,0x06,0x99},
{0x9c,0x42,0x50,0xf4,0x91,0xef,0x98,0x7a,0x33,0x54,0x0b,0x43,0xed,0xcf,0xac,0x62},
{0xe4,0xb3,0x1c,0xa9,0xc9,0x08,0xe8,0x95,0x80,0xdf,0x94,0xfa,0x75,0x8f,0x3f,0xa6},
{0x47,0x07,0xa7,0xfc,0xf3,0x73,0x17,0xba,0x83,0x59,0x3c,0x19,0xe6,0x85,0x4f,0xa8},
{0x68,0x6b,0x81,0xb2,0x71,0x64,0xda,0x8b,0xf8,0xeb,0x0f,0x4b,0x70,0x56,0x9d,0x35},
{0x1e,0x24,0x0e,0x5e,0x63,0x58,0xd1,0xa2,0x25,0x22,0x7c,0x3b,0x01,0x21,0x78,0x87},
{0xd4,0x00,0x46,0x57,0x9f,0xd3,0x27,0x52,0x4c,0x36,0x02,0xe7,0xa0,0xc4,0xc8,0x9e},
{0xea,0xbf,0x8a,0xd2,0x40,0xc7,0x38,0xb5,0xa3,0xf7,0xf2,0xce,0xf9,0x61,0x15,0xa1},
{0xe0,0xae,0x5d,0xa4,0x9b,0x34,0x1a,0x55,0xad,0x93,0x32,0x30,0xf5,0x8c,0xb1,0xe3},
{0x1d,0xf6,0xe2,0x2e,0x82,0x66,0xca,0x60,0xc0,0x29,0x23,0xab,0x0d,0x53,0x4e,0x6f},
{0xd5,0xdb,0x37,0x45,0xde,0xfd,0x8e,0x2f,0x03,0xff,0x6a,0x72,0x6d,0x6c,0x5b,0x51},
{0x8d,0x1b,0xaf,0x92,0xbb,0xdd,0xbc,0x7f,0x11,0xd9,0x5c,0x41,0x1f,0x10,0x5a,0xd8},
{0x0a,0xc1,0x31,0x88,0xa5,0xcd,0x7b,0xbd,0x2d,0x74,0xd0,0x12,0xb8,0xe5,0xb4,0xb0},
{0x89,0x69,0x97,0x4a,0x0c,0x96,0x77,0x7e,0x65,0xb9,0xf1,0x09,0xc5,0x6e,0xc6,0x84},
{0x18,0xf0,0x7d,0xec,0x3a,0xdc,0x4d,0x20,0x79,0xee,0x5f,0x3e,0xd7,0xcb,0x39,0x48}
};

/* System parameter */
static const unsigned long FK[4] = {0xa3b1bac6,0x56aa3350,0x677d9197,0xb27022dc};

/* fixed parameter */
static const unsigned long CK[32] =
{
0x00070e15,0x1c232a31,0x383f464d,0x545b6269,
0x70777e85,0x8c939aa1,0xa8afb6bd,0xc4cbd2d9,
0xe0e7eef5,0xfc030a11,0x181f262d,0x343b4249,
0x50575e65,0x6c737a81,0x888f969d,0xa4abb2b9,
0xc0c7ced5,0xdce3eaf1,0xf8ff060d,0x141b2229,
0x30373e45,0x4c535a61,0x686f767d,0x848b9299,
0xa0a7aeb5,0xbcc3cad1,0xd8dfe6ed,0xf4fb0209,
0x10171e25,0x2c333a41,0x484f565d,0x646b7279
};


/*
 * private function:
 * look up in SboxTable and get the related value.
 * args:    [in] inch: 0x00~0xFF (8 bits unsigned value).
 */
static unsigned char sm4Sbox(unsigned char inch)
{
    unsigned char *pTable = (unsigned char *)SboxTable;
    unsigned char retVal = (unsigned char)(pTable[inch]);
    return retVal;
}

/*
 * private F(Lt) function:
 * "T algorithm" == "L algorithm" + "t algorithm".
 * args:    [in] a: a is a 32 bits unsigned value;
 * return: c: c is calculated with line algorithm "L" and nonline algorithm "t"
 */
static unsigned long sm4Lt(unsigned long ka)
{
    unsigned long bb = 0;
    unsigned long c = 0;
    unsigned char a[4];
    unsigned char b[4];
    PUT_ULONG_BE(ka,a,0)
    b[0] = sm4Sbox(a[0]);
    b[1] = sm4Sbox(a[1]);
    b[2] = sm4Sbox(a[2]);
    b[3] = sm4Sbox(a[3]);
    GET_ULONG_BE(bb,b,0)
    c =bb^(ROTL(bb, 2))^(ROTL(bb, 10))^(ROTL(bb, 18))^(ROTL(bb, 24));
    return c;
}

/*
 * private F function:
 * Calculating and getting encryption/decryption contents.
 * args:    [in] x0: original contents;
 * args:    [in] x1: original contents;
 * args:    [in] x2: original contents;
 * args:    [in] x3: original contents;
 * args:    [in] rk: encryption/decryption key;
 * return the contents of encryption/decryption contents.
 */
static unsigned long sm4F(unsigned long x0, unsigned long x1, unsigned long x2, unsigned long x3, unsigned long rk)
{
    return (x0^sm4Lt(x1^x2^x3^rk));
}


/* private function:
 * Calculating round encryption key.
 * args:    [in] a: a is a 32 bits unsigned value;
 * return: sk[i]: i{0,1,2,3,...31}.
 */
static unsigned long sm4CalciRK(unsigned long ka)
{
    unsigned long bb = 0;
    unsigned long rk = 0;
    unsigned char a[4];
    unsigned char b[4];
    PUT_ULONG_BE(ka,a,0)
    b[0] = sm4Sbox(a[0]);
    b[1] = sm4Sbox(a[1]);
    b[2] = sm4Sbox(a[2]);
    b[3] = sm4Sbox(a[3]);
    GET_ULONG_BE(bb,b,0)
    rk = bb^(ROTL(bb, 13))^(ROTL(bb, 23));
    return rk;
}

static void sm4_setkey( unsigned long SK[32], unsigned char key[16] )
{
    unsigned long MK[4];
    unsigned long k[36];
    unsigned long i = 0;

    GET_ULONG_BE( MK[0], key, 0 );
    GET_ULONG_BE( MK[1], key, 4 );
    GET_ULONG_BE( MK[2], key, 8 );
    GET_ULONG_BE( MK[3], key, 12 );
    k[0] = MK[0]^FK[0];
    k[1] = MK[1]^FK[1];
    k[2] = MK[2]^FK[2];
    k[3] = MK[3]^FK[3];
    for(; i<32; i++)
    {
        k[i+4] = k[i] ^ (sm4CalciRK(k[i+1]^k[i+2]^k[i+3]^CK[i]));
        SK[i] = k[i+4];
    }

}

/*
 * SM4 standard one round processing
 *
 */
static void sm4_one_round( unsigned long sk[32],
                    unsigned char input[16],
                    unsigned char output[16] )
{
    unsigned long i = 0;
    unsigned long ulbuf[36];

    memset(ulbuf, 0, sizeof(ulbuf));
    GET_ULONG_BE( ulbuf[0], input, 0 )
    GET_ULONG_BE( ulbuf[1], input, 4 )
    GET_ULONG_BE( ulbuf[2], input, 8 )
    GET_ULONG_BE( ulbuf[3], input, 12 )
    while(i<32)
    {
        ulbuf[i+4] = sm4F(ulbuf[i], ulbuf[i+1], ulbuf[i+2], ulbuf[i+3], sk[i]);
// #ifdef _DEBUG
//          printf("rk(%02d) = 0x%08x,  X(%02d) = 0x%08x \n",i,sk[i], i, ulbuf[i+4] );
// #endif
        i++;
    }
    PUT_ULONG_BE(ulbuf[35],output,0);
    PUT_ULONG_BE(ulbuf[34],output,4);
    PUT_ULONG_BE(ulbuf[33],output,8);
    PUT_ULONG_BE(ulbuf[32],output,12);
}

/*
 * SM4 key schedule (128-bit, encryption)
 */
void sm4_setkey_enc( sm4_context *ctx, unsigned char key[16] )
{
    ctx->mode = SM4_ENCRYPT;
    sm4_setkey( ctx->sk, key );
}

/*
 * SM4 key schedule (128-bit, decryption)
 */
void sm4_setkey_dec( sm4_context *ctx, unsigned char key[16] )
{
    int i;
    ctx->mode = SM4_ENCRYPT;
    sm4_setkey( ctx->sk, key );
    for( i = 0; i < 16; i ++ )
    {
        SWAP( ctx->sk[ i ], ctx->sk[ 31-i] );
    }
}


/*
 * SM4-ECB block encryption/decryption
 */

void sm4_crypt_ecb( sm4_context *ctx,
                   int mode,
                   int length,
                   unsigned char *input,
                   unsigned char *output)
{
    while( length > 0 )
    {
        sm4_one_round( ctx->sk, input, output );
        input  += 16;
        output += 16;
        length -= 16;
    }

}

/*
 * SM4-CBC buffer encryption/decryption
 */
void sm4_crypt_cbc( sm4_context *ctx,
                    int mode,
                    int length,
                    unsigned char iv[16],
                    unsigned char *input,
                    unsigned char *output )
{
    int i;
    unsigned char temp[16];

    if( mode == SM4_ENCRYPT )
    {
        while( length > 0 )
        {
            for( i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
                output[i] = (unsigned char)( input[i] ^ iv[i] );

            sm4_one_round( ctx->sk, output, output );
            memcpy( iv, output, 16 );

            input  += 16;
            output += 16;
            length -= 16;
        }
    }
    else /* SM4_DECRYPT */
    {
        while( length > 0 )
        {
            memcpy( temp, input, 16 );
            sm4_one_round( ctx->sk, input, output );

            for( i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
                output[i] = (unsigned char)( output[i] ^ iv[i] );

            memcpy( iv, temp, 16 );

            input  += 16;
            output += 16;
            length -= 16;
        }
    }
}
```

sm4test.c:

```
/*
 * SM4/SMS4 algorithm test programme
 * 2012-4-21
 */

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "sm4.h"

int main()
{
    unsigned char key[16] = {0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67,0x89,0xab,0xcd,0xef,0xfe,0xdc,0xba,0x98,0x76,0x54,0x32,0x10};
    unsigned char input[16] = {0x01,0x23,0x45,0x67,0x89,0xab,0xcd,0xef,0xfe,0xdc,0xba,0x98,0x76,0x54,0x32,0x10};
    unsigned char output[16];
    sm4_context ctx;
    unsigned long i;

    //encrypt standard testing vector
    sm4_setkey_enc(&ctx,key);
    sm4_crypt_ecb(&ctx,1,16,input,output);
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        printf("%02x ", output[i]);
    printf("\n");

    //decrypt testing
    sm4_setkey_dec(&ctx,key);
    sm4_crypt_ecb(&ctx,0,16,output,output);
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        printf("%02x ", output[i]);
    printf("\n");

    //decrypt 1M times testing vector based on standards.
    i = 0;
    sm4_setkey_enc(&ctx,key);
    while (i<1000000) 
    {
        sm4_crypt_ecb(&ctx,1,16,input,input);
        i++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        printf("%02x ", input[i]);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could look into streaming modes such as CTR mode, but they require a nonce. If you can generate nonces in your system without saving them, then you can use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to use a block cipher to encrypt/decrypt a plaintext of arbitrary length is to pad it to a whole number of blocks with a known padding method - for example, PKCS7 - and then use a block chaining method to encrypt the sequence of blocks. When you decrypt, the padding tells you how many bytes to remove to recover the original length of plaintext. The ciphertext will always be a whole number of blocks in length. In your case, there is only a single block anyway because your plaintext is so short.

If you are fixed length, and you know that your input/output is always 64 bits, then you could just discard the later 64 bits. Otherwise, look at a block cipher chaining mode (CBC, CTR, GCM etc) and padding - this is the normal way a block cipher is used.